# How the textfield interactive using livecode?

Tags: livecode

I need to do certain replacement, but i don't want to replace this globally.
eg:- **replace bad with good in field "MytextField"**.
But i don't want to replace this bad with good globally. is there any option for asking yes and no options. if i press yes it will replace, otherwise it will go to the next occurance for asking yes and no and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this, but try this experiment. Make a field with this in it:

> aa red aa red aa red aa red

Now make a button, and put this in its script:

```
  local latest
on mouseUp
   put 0 into latest
   startFinding fld 1.0
end mouseUp

on startFinding tText,tOffset
   if the optionKey is down then exit to top
   put wordOffset("red",fld 1,tOffset) into latest
   answer "Change word" && (latest + tOffset) && "?" with "Change" or    "Continue"
    If it = "change" then put "green" into word (latest + tOffset) of fld 1
    add latest to tOffset
    if tOffset < the number of words of fld 1 then startFinding fld 1,tOffset
end startFinding
```

You might embellish this by including some of the preceding and following words with each run, so that the context can be presented to the user.

Craig Newwman